# What is the time complexity of this algorithm (Big-O)?

Tags: c, algorithm, time, big-o

I am still trying to understand the BigO notation and time complexity, however, I am really not sure what is the time complexity of this algorithm (my code).

```
// 03_BeaverConstructions.c
// Created for FIKS on 28/12/2013 by Dominik Hadl
//
// Time complexity: O(N+M)
// Space complexity: O(N)
// ------------------------------------------
// LICENSE (MIT)
// Copyright (c) 2013 Dominik Hadl
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.
// ------------------------------------------

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// ------------------------------------------
// Setup
// ------------------------------------------

#define MAX_PROFILE_LENGTH 10000
#define NO_VALUE -99999

#define BLOCK_VOLUME 1
#define SLOPE_VOLUME 0.5

const char kSlopeRise = '/';
const char kSlopeLower = '\\';
const char kSlopeStay = '_';

// ------------------------------------------
// Structs
// ------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
    int start_elevation;
    float current_volume;
} Lake;

typedef struct
{
    int location;
    int elevation;
} Peak;

// ------------------------------------------
// Declarations
// ------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]);
float get_water_volume_of_profile(char const *hill_profile);

// ------------------------------------------
// Main
// ------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // Get the profile
    char hill_profile[MAX_PROFILE_LENGTH + 1];
    fgets(hill_profile, MAX_PROFILE_LENGTH + 1, stdin);

    // Calculate the volume
    float volume = get_water_volume_of_profile(hill_profile);

    // Print it!
    printf("%0.1f\n", volume);

    return 0;
}

// ------------------------------------------
// Calculation
// ------------------------------------------

float get_water_volume_of_profile(char const *hill_profile)
{
    float total_volume = 0; 
    int current_elevation = 0, number_of_peaks = 0, last_peak_index = 0;

    // Get the actual length of the hill profile    
    int profile_length = strlen(hill_profile);

    // Prepare the peaks and lakes in the hill profile
    Peak peaks[profile_length / 2];
    Lake lake = {NO_VALUE, 0};

    // First, get all the peaks
    for (int i = 0; i < profile_length; i++)
    {
        char current_char = hill_profile[i];
        char next_char = hill_profile[i + 1];

        switch (current_char)
        {
            case kSlopeRise:
                current_elevation += 1;
                break;
            case kSlopeLower:
                current_elevation -= 1;
                break;
            case kSlopeStay:
                break;
        }

        if (next_char == '\n')
        {
            peaks[number_of_peaks].location = i + 1;
            peaks[number_of_peaks].elevation = current_elevation;
            number_of_peaks++;
            break;
        }

        if (current_char == kSlopeRise &&
            (next_char == kSlopeLower || next_char == kSlopeStay))
        {
            peaks[number_of_peaks].location = i + 1;
            peaks[number_of_peaks].elevation = current_elevation;
            number_of_peaks++;
        }
    }

    // Now, go through the profile and get the water volume
    current_elevation = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < profile_length; i++)
    {
        // Get current char and decide what to do
        char current_char = hill_profile[i];
        switch (current_char)
        {
            case kSlopeRise:
            {
                if (lake.start_elevation != NO_VALUE &&
                    lake.start_elevation > current_elevation)
                {
                    lake.current_volume += SLOPE_VOLUME;
                }

                // Increase the elevation
                current_elevation++;

                if (lake.start_elevation == current_elevation)
                {
                    total_volume += lake.current_volume;

                    lake.start_elevation = NO_VALUE;
                    lake.current_volume = 0;
                    break;
                }

                if (lake.start_elevation != NO_VALUE)
                {
                    int elevation_diff = abs(lake.start_elevation - current_elevation);
                    if (elevation_diff > 1)
                    {
                        lake.current_volume += (elevation_diff - 1) * BLOCK_VOLUME;
                    }
                }

                break;
            }
            case kSlopeLower:
            {
                current_elevation--; // Lower the elevation

                // Set elevation where water starts if not already set
                if (lake.start_elevation == NO_VALUE)
                {
                    for (int p = last_peak_index; p < number_of_peaks; p++)
                    {
                        if (peaks[p].elevation >= current_elevation + 1 &&
                            peaks[p].location > i)
                        {
                            lake.start_elevation = current_elevation + 1;
                            last_peak_index = p;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (lake.start_elevation == NO_VALUE) 
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                lake.current_volume += SLOPE_VOLUME;

                int elevation_diff = abs(lake.start_elevation - current_elevation);
                if (elevation_diff > 1)
                {
                    lake.current_volume += elevation_diff * BLOCK_VOLUME;
                }

                break;
            }
            case kSlopeStay:
            {
                if (lake.start_elevation != NO_VALUE)
                {
                    int elevation_diff = abs(lake.start_elevation - current_elevation);
                    lake.current_volume += elevation_diff * BLOCK_VOLUME;
                }   
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the total water volume
    return total_volume;
}
```

I am not sure if it is O(N), but I don't think so, as there is one nested loop in the second for loop. However, it probably is not O(N^2) also... more something like O((N^2)/2).

Could somebody give me advice?

Comment: `O((N^2)/2)` is NOT a different complexity than `O(N^2)`

Comment: @SlaterTyranus `O((N^2)/2)` is a perfectly legal complexity.  It is just equal to `O(N^2)`.

Comment: That is a lot of code.  Why don't you summarize the algorithm in pseudo-code?

Comment: @Andrey fair point, edited to be more accurate

Comment: I find it pretty surprising that the comment about the supposedly illegal complexity got 2 immediate upvotes.

Comment: @Andrey Although "illegal" was too strong of a word, I am relatively sure people upvoted because Slater was attempting to clear up a misconception the OP seems to have.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Thanks for clearing that up. Will remember it.

Comment: @Andrey Sorry, will do that next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity of the algorithm is `O(n + m)` where `n` is the size of your input and `m` is the number of "peaks," whatever these are.

The reason is that the core algorithm consists of two loops that run roughly `n` times.  One of the loops contains an inner loop.  We need to count how many times the body of the inner loop is executed.

The inner loop is run when you encounter a peak, and it looks like the total number of times the *body* of the loop executes is roughly the number of peaks you have.  It does not matter that the loop is nested: for the complexity calculation, the *total* number of iterations of the body is what counts.

(Usually a nested loop's iteration count is multiplied rather than added because it is executed in full every iteration of the outer loop, but this is not the case here.  You logically are iterating (in the inner loop) from the first peak to the last; notice that you keep track (using `p`) of where you `break` out of the inner loop between iterations of the outer one, and start from `p` when you return to the inner loop.)

Comment: I know this question is not about space complexity, but isn't the space complexity also O(n + m) then?

Comment: It would be, except that your arrays' sizes are statically set to `1000` or whatever, so the space complexity is actually `O(1)`.  (The program will use the same amount of memory no matter what input it is given.)  If you dynamically allocated the arrays to be exactly as big as is necessary for a given input, then yes, it looks like the space complexity would be `O(n + m)`.

Comment: Ok, and if I would allocate the first array statically (hill_profile) and then the second (peaks) dynamically to strlen(hill_profile)/2 ? Would it be then O(1 + M)?

Comment: @DominikHadl Looks that way

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something? I'd rather you have just provided the pseudocode/or necessary lines of code, but it looks like it's just two for loops in a row, and the second for loop has a nested loop. That will be O(N^2), no? As your dataset increases, the time complexity should be proportional to the square of your dataset...

I never mastered this subject though, if someone wants to correct me.

**Edit--** See Comments for why this is wrong..!

Comment: The two loops are not the same length.

Comment: Sounds close to the truth, although to know for sure it is necessary to decipher whether `for (int p = last_peak_index; p < number_of_peaks; p++)` is really linear in his input set size.

Comment: This may not be true.  The inner for-loop is based on `p`, and it is hard to tell if `p` is based on `i` in any meaningful way.  For example, if the `p` loop is independent of `i`, then the complexity will just be `O(n)`, otherwise it will be higher.

Comment: Looks like the number of peaks depends on the actual input, and not just the size of the input.

Comment: @Jordan ahh, I was wondering how you would represent that, after reading the first comment above^ .. that does make sense, and it probably IS just O(n) then? (If you had to guess)

Comment: @Andrey so, two indepdent inputs? therefore, O(n)?

Comment: Not quite, writing an answer now.

Comment: @HC_ This is more complicated code then I have time to delve into right now, but if I had to _guess_, i would say yes, O(N), looks like Andrey may be writing up a more complete analysis.